# Why Bootstrap stops working if route has two "/" signs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bootstrap-4, routes

If I use `/something` it works fine, but when I use `/something/somethingelse` bootstrap does not work.
I tried everything, this behavior is completely independent from what can be found inside the .ejs file, and only affected by the number of "/"-s.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('static'));

// Load routing
require('./route/index')(app);

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
});
```

All of my middlewares are empty like this except render:

```
module.exports = function(objectrepository) {

    return function(req, res, next) {
        return next();
    };
};
```

renderMW:

```
module.exports = function (objectrepository, viewName) {
    return function (req, res) {
        res.render(viewName);
        console.log('render: ' + viewName);
    };
};
```

header.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c16b9f9cc1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons/mobirise-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons2/mobirise2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dropdown/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
```

assets.ejs:

```
</body>
<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/smoothscroll/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="assets/dropdown/js/nav-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/dropdown/js/navbar-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/touchswipe/jquery.touch-swipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/theme/js/script.js"></script>
```

footer.ejs:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

It does not matter if I use header.ejs, assets.ejs, footer.ejs or simply make one .ejs file with the whole part of the code. I tried with all routes the format "/../something" and bootstrap always stop working on that route.

Normal working with 1 "/" in route: https://prnt.sc/qcaoqu

Bad working with 2 "/" in route: https://prnt.sc/qcapnt

What is causing this problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: How do you load bootstrap into your project?

Comment: added bootstrap loading parts that I use in .ejs files

Comment: Have you checked browser's console for any errors related to bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by putting an extra "/" sign before every line starting with assets.

Bad one:

```
<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fixed one:

```
<script src="/assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```